# Disable the space button for inputs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I got a textbox on my form. I want the users to not have the ability to press space in the keyboard. I'm using the code below to disable spacing. I don't understand why it isn't working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Counter File</title>

<script>
function noSpaces()
{
    $("input").on("keydown", function (e) 
    {
        return e.which !== 32;
    }); 
}
</script>  

</head>

<body>

    ID Number: <input type="text" name="IDNumb" id="IDNumb" onkeydown="noSpaces()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Would appear to work fine if you did.

Comment: I'm not sure and where would i include JQuery?

Comment: The `onkeydown` event subscribes to the `noSpaces` function which then re-subcribes using jquery for input for keydown. Pick one or the other but do not subscribe multiple times because now you add a new subscription with every event call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Counter File</title>

</head>

<body>
    ID Number: <input type="text" name="IDNumb" id="IDNumb">
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $("input").on("keydown", function (e) 
    {
        return e.which !== 32;
    }); 
</script>  
</html>
```

- The onkeydown event subscribes to the noSpaces function which then re-subcribes using jquery for input for keydown. Pick one or the other but do not subscribe multiple times because now you add a new subscription with every event call.
- Added CDN reference to jquery

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to disable the spacing for specific inputs using the id?

Comment: @taji01 - you can use [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). Example above: `$("#IDNumb").on(... etc`

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input").on("keydown", function (e) 
        {
            return e.which !== 32;
        }); 
})
```

I guess this code is enough for you you don't need to define  onkeydown="noSpaces()" and noSpaces function

Answer (score 1):

I prefer would use `keyup` and would solve it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Counter File</title>
</head>

<body>
    ID Number: <input type="text" name="IDNumb" id="IDNumb">
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $("input").on("keyup", function (e) 
    {
        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included jquery library. You first have to include that and then this will work.

```
$("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
    return e.which !== 32;
});
```